Why is it showing error while installing 'shadcn ui'?
I started a next.js full stack project and I was installing shadcn-ui than while doing it I faced the error
when I tried to install shadcn-ui by typing
npx shadcn-ui@latest init
I got the error message
node:fs:601
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
  ^

Error: package.json: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'package.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:601:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
    at Object.readFileSync (C:\Users\smara\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\125ee17d583c4e03\node_modules\jsonfile\index.js:50:22)
    at _e (file:///C:/Users/smara/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/125ee17d583c4e03/node_modules/shadcn-ui/dist/index.js:245:5248)
    at _t (file:///C:/Users/smara/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/125ee17d583c4e03/node_modules/shadcn-ui/dist/index.js:245:5379)
    at file:///C:/Users/smara/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/125ee17d583c4e03/node_modules/shadcn-ui/dist/index.js:245:5606
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'package.json'
}

please help me with this

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Make sure you create your Nextjs project with typescript, tailwind, and eslint
npx create-next-app@latest my-app --typescript --tailwind --eslint

Then in the project directory run
npx shadcn-ui@latest init

And follow the instructions
Reference: https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/installation/next

I have all these steps and then run the command but still it is showing error

try npm cache clean --force to clear npm cache and then again npx shadcn-ui@latest init

Are you sure that you're running the installing script in the root directory where the package.json is?

yes I'm sure that I m running there only
